# Google Drive no longer prompts to install Chrome App

Tags: google-drive-api, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

We have a Hosted Web App in the Chrome Web Store which integrates with Google Drive.

Since upgrading to *"The New Drive"*, users who attempt to open files created by our app (but do not have the app installed) are no longer prompted to install the app from the Chrome Web Store. They used to get a dialog like this:
[image: Example Dialog]

Now, Drive simply opens a new tab & directs the user directly to our app's URL without inviting to install - which is not what we want, we want the user to have it in their app list. Reverting back to the "Old Drive" does not fix the problem. Once the user has upgraded to the new drive, it stops working.

The manifest for the app looks like this:

```js
{
    "name": "My App",
    "version": "1.0.7",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Short Description",
    "container": "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
    "api_console_project_id": "MY_PROJECT_ID",
    "gdrive_mime_types": {
        "http://drive.google.com/intents/opendrivedoc": [{
            "type": ["application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.myExtension", "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.MY_PROJECT_ID"],
            "href": "https://my.url.com/drive",
            "title": "Open",
            "disposition": "window"
        }]
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "ft-icon-96-96.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "https://my.url.com/welcome"
        }
    }
}
```

**Sidenote:** Possibly related, but another odd thing is that users who *do* have the app installed already cannot disconnect the app from drive. It just keeps showing up again regardless. But this seems more like a Drive bug than an app configuration error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may help you :

[Web Store Inline Installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation)

Here it says :

> The HTML page on your site from which you want inline installation to
>   occur must contain one or more  tags in the  section
>   referencing the items that the user can install. Each  tag must
>   have the following format:

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">
```

and you can trigger an inline installation using:

```
chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)
```

also check if app is already installed using:

```
 chrome.app.isInstalled
```

Comment: This will work perfect for a workaround! Much better than what we have in place at the minute! Still would like to know if this is intended behaviour

Comment: from what I see  , this must be a google drive issue , and you have to check bug reports if someone reported such bug before , if not then you should do.